# Pre-commit Husky doesn't run npx lint-staged

Tags: git, eslint, tsx, lint-staged, git-husky

When I git commit. Pre-commit Husky doesn't run npx lint-staged.

In Package.json, I add husky and lint-staged.

```
{
  "name": "bookstore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{html, css, tsx, jsx, ts, js}": "prettier --write",
    "*.tsx": [
      "eslint"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.18.52",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^14.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

.husky/pre-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

When I make some error and run command: npx lint-staged
I got warning errors as I expected.

[image]

But when I commit the code with an error, Husky doesn't trigger git hooks `npx lint-staged` like it is supposed to run.

[image]